# Unable to pick data from JDBC response using Groovy Script

Tags: jdbc, groovy, soapui

I have the following XML which is generated from a JDBC response step:

```
<ResultSet fetchSize="64">
    <Row rowNumber="1">
        <TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_CODE>022</TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_CODE>
        <TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_TYPE>N</TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_TYPE>
        <TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_VAL>1</TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_VAL>
        <TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_TYPE>C</TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_TYPE>
    </Row>
    <Row rowNumber="2">
        <TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_CODE>023</TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_CODE>
        <TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_TYPE>N</TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_TYPE>
        <TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_VAL>3</TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_VAL>
        <TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_TYPE>R</TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_TYPE>
    </Row>
    <Row rowNumber="3">
        <TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_CODE>030</TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_CODE>
        <TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_TYPE>N</TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_TYPE>
        <TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_VAL>1</TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_VAL>
        <TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_TYPE>C</TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_TYPE>
    </Row>
```

I am trying to grab these values into an assert in a later step. I want the values to arrive in a *data map*.

I have the following Groovy script in my assert which I am hoping will pick up the values from the JDBC response and assign them to each data mapping stated in the script:

```
def jdbcResponse = context.expand( '${JDBC Request for expected results#ResponseAsXml}')

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(jdbcResponse)

def expected = xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'Row'}.collect{ [
              LimitCode       : it.TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_CODE.text(),
              LimitType       : it.TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_TYPE.text(),
              LimitPeriod     : it.TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_VAL.text(),
              LimitPeriodType : it.TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_TYPE.text()
             ]
          }.sort {it.LimitCode}
```

But the values form the JDBC response are not arriving. 'expected' looks like this:

```
Thu Oct 12 10:51:05 WST 2017:INFO:
[{LimitCode=, LimitType=, LimitPeriod=, LimitPeriodType=}, 
{LimitCode=, LimitType=, LimitPeriod=, LimitPeriodType=}, 
{LimitCode=, LimitType=, LimitPeriod=, LimitPeriodType=},]
```

I can see that 'xml' is coming through as follows:

> Thu Oct 12 10:55:19 WST 2017:INFO:022N1C023N3R030N1C033N5R043N3R093N1C601S1C

Any ideas why I can't allocate these values from JDBC response XML into the data map values?

Comment: Matt, please check the solution to see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because, the element name has `.`. Hence, you need to put the element name between the *single quote(')* as shown below:

```
def expected = xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'Row'}.collect{ [
              LimitCode       : it.'TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_CODE'.text(),
              LimitType       : it.'TW341_LIMITDEFN.LIMIT_TYPE'.text(),
              LimitPeriod     : it.'TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_VAL'.text(),
              LimitPeriodType : it.'TW341_LIMITDEFN.PERIOD_TYPE'.text()
             ]
          }.sort {it.LimitCode}
```

Comment: Thank you again Rao. Small thing to miss out but all so important!